# Python output readable in Matlab

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I am a Python newbie and am trying to write a numpy array into format readable in Matlab in the following format into an array [xi, yi, ti], separated by a semi-colon.

In python, I am able to currently write it in the following form, which is a numpy array printed on screen/written to file as [[xi yi ti]].

Here is the code:

```
import math
import random
import numpy as np
SPOT = []
f = open('data_dump.txt', 'a')
for i in range(10):
    X = random.randrange(6)
    Y = random.randrange(10)
    T = random.randrange(5)
    SPOT.append([X,Y,T])
SPOT = np.array(SPOT)
f.write(str(SPOT[:]))   
f.close()
```

Please suggest how I should proceed to be able to write this data in Matlab readable format as mentioned above. Thanks in advance!

Sree.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding this code to it. Nothing can be done with it as a comment

Comment: What do the first few lines of data_dump.txt look like? You can probably read it into Matlab as is.

Answer (score 2):

It is not very necessary to write your `array` into a special format. Write it into a normal `csv` and use [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) to open it in `matlab`.

In `numpy` side, write your `array` using `np.savetxt('some_name.txt', aar, delimiter=' ')`

Comment: Thanks everyone! @CT Zhu: I tried using np.savetxt now and it seems to work! Added the following and it writes into a format that is readable in Matlab as an array directly. Thanks again! np.savetxt('test.txt', SPOT, fmt = '%10.5f', delimiter=',', newline = ';\n', header='data =[...', footer=']', comments = '#')

Answer (score 2):

Try `scipy.io` to export data for `Matlab`

```
import scipy.io as sio

matlab_data = dict(SPOT=SPOT)
sio.savemat('data_dump.mat', matlab_data)
```

`data_dump.mat` is `Matlab` data. For more detail, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have scipy than you can do:

```
import scipy.io
scipy.io.savemat('/tmp/test.mat', dict(SPOT=SPOT))
```

And in matlab:

```
a=load('/tmp/test.mat');
a.SPOT % should have your data
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone and thanks @CT Zhu for letting me know!

Since I am not using Scipy, I tried using np.savetxt and it seems to work! Added the following and it writes into a format that is readable in Matlab as an array directly. Thanks again!

```
np.savetxt('test.txt', SPOT, fmt = '%10.5f', delimiter=',', newline = ';\n', header='data =[...', footer=']', comments = '#')
```

Cheers!
Sree.